# Confusion in field after CS undergraduate degree

Tags: masters, mathematics, computer-science, changing-fields

Thank you for hearing me out.

I'm currently enrolled in a CS Undergrad course and will be coming out of it next year. ( 2018 ). One thing straight is I love mathematics. Anyways let's proceed with the actual confusion. I'll be coming out next year. Then what?

These are my options and I'm oscillating between them from a week. ( ..no sleep )

- Go forward and get a Master degree on Computer Science specializing on computational neuroscience and vision. ( perceiving systems ). Then a PhD in Computer Vision or Computational Neuroscience, squeezing academic and industry internships. Later on join academia, research.
- Go forward and get a Masters in Mathematics, PhD follows. ( in differential topology ). Post Doc work for some years and then join a top University as a faculty, teach, research.
- Go forward and with Masters in Mathematics and Physics and then a PhD in String theory, ( as string theory requires a lot of math in particular group theory, category theory, differential and algebraic topology and gauge theory which I'm into and had brief exposure with particle physics as in internship( mostly was writing code and analysis in ROOT (with CERN, remotely) ( `C++` ) ). Then join CERN or an University, teach, research.

Alright. Now my skills and knowledge.

- **Mathematics.** I am proficient in engineering math ( linear algebra, calculus I, II, III, ODE, PDE, discrete math, basic statistics and probability ). Also I I have a solid grasp on introductory group theory, algebraic and differential topology, real analysis. Software side, I know Matlab well.
- **Physics.** I know high school physics well. I also had gained knowledge of particle physics during the internship but on an introductory level. That's it.
- **Computer Science.** : I have taken these fundamental courses during my undergrad. ( OS, compiler design, Database, `C++/Java/C`, Algorithms, Data Structures, basics of automata theory, optimization, computer graphics, electronics ). I am proficient in `C/C++`, I can manage `Java`.
- **Biology/Neuroscience:** I know high school biology well. I have taken the Harvardx, MOOC ( [Fundamentals of Neuroscience](https://www.mcb80x.org/) )
- Projects and other stuff: **Computer Vision**: I have worked on AR UI interfaces ( and currently writing a paper on this with my classmates) and currently working on eye tracking. **Computer Graphics**: I have worked on fluid simulations, multigrid solvers and image synthesis techniques ( PBR ), raytracing. Apart from this I used to code competitively and had gone to zonal ACM-ICPC level but now I have sort of lost the touch of it.

I want to go into academia. ( maybe research R&D departments of companies for a short time just a have a dip into the industry. ) Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a shopping question here.

Comment: If only the journey from undergrad to tenured prof at a top uni was as easy as this question makes it sound...

Comment: @astronat I meant top universities in my country. We don't have tenure as such. It's directly being a central government employee once you clear the interview.

Comment: @Coder if it's off topic tell me the best place to ask.

Comment: @therewasaduck there isn't a stackexchange for this type of question. It really depends on your own personal goals and motivations. Asking a bunch of strangers on the internet what to do with your life is plainly foolhardy. If you don't know what to do seek out a guidance counselor at your school or find a mentor among the staff that can make more specific suggestions to your area. If you really don't have any focus then try industry for a while. Internships are a great way to get your feet wet while still earning some money to live on.

Comment: @therewasaduck hasn't managed to state the question clearly, but I think this question can be significantly edited (probably rewritten), rather than shutting it down. In essence, the OP needs to evaluate entry requirements and skills necessary for a PhD to decide which postgraduate degree to take. That seems like a reasonable question to ask on SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned postgraduate degrees in Computer Science, Mathematics, and Mathematics & Physics, and PhDs in Computer Vision, Computational Neuroscience, Mathematics, and Mathematics & Physics. I recommend that you study a postgraduate degree which maximises your options onto a PhD. Since you already have an undergraduate degree in Computer Science, that probably means that a postgraduate degree in Mathematics or Mathematics & Physics is the best fit.

Comment: won't be my non adequate knowledge of mathematics and physics curb my entry to top graduate courses?

Comment: *Since you already have an ..., that probably means t... Mathematics & Physics is the best fit.* -- I don't agree with your somewhat direct recommendation for a grad. school degree in Math/Phy. A undergrad degree in Comp. Sc. is actually fit for every possible discipline you could imagine for e.g. computational chemistry, computational biology, computational economics, though the majority of them would be applied. But, whether it is a **best** fit is questionable on various things due to which the question has been shut down as a shoppign question.

Comment: @Coder, you've misquoted me: I suggested Mathematics or Mathematics & Physics. A postgraduate degree in Computer Science doesn't seem as beneficial as either Mathematics or Mathematics & Physics. Do you believe Computer Science is better? Or are you quibbling over my use of _best_, in which case it is worth noting it is preceded by _probably means_.

Comment: @therewasaduck, I don't understand your comment. I recommended postgraduate degree in Mathematics or Mathematics & Physics. Perhaps you meant "would knowledge of mathematics (and possibly physics) rather than further knowledge of computer science preclude entry to a top graduate course in computer science?" Assuming a postgraduate degree in computer science isn't a pre-requisite to a PhD in computer science, then no. Your knowledge of mathematics will be just as valuable (especially for Computer Vision, I can't comment on Computational Neuroscience).